# Solution to Einstein field equations for an electron with energy $E$?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime

I realise that the spacetime curvature would be extremely small, I'm just interested to know. Let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/523982/2451

Comment: Hi Josh Crawford. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Hi Qmechanic, sorry, I forgot about my previous question. I'd like to edit this question so that it is not the same as the previous one, so can you please open this question back up.

Comment: Tip: If you edit the post, it will automatically enter the review queue.